# Noop for Func<Task>?

Tags: c#

There is a function

```
async Task MyFuncation(Func<Task> f)
{
    // do something
    //
    await f();
}
```

Sometimes I need to call the function but don't have anything for parameter `f` so I pass it `async () => { }`. Is there a noop function for it?

```
await RunMyFuncation(async () => { }); // I still need to call Run
```

Comment: Can you modify the method?

Comment: @TaW one is for the syntax error and one is for noop quotations. They are not the same. Another one is deleted.

Comment: @RufusL yes I can.

Comment: In that case, you could make the argument optional, and do a `null` check inside the method before trying to execute it: `async Task Run(Func<Task> f = null) { if (f != null) await f(); }`, and then just call it like: `await Run();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noop that you are looking for is [Task.CompletedTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> Gets a task that has already completed successfully.

However, you still need to pass a lambda since the method requires a `Func<T>` not a Task as an argument.

```
await Run(() => Task.CompletedTask);
```

This might not be that different from using a empty block as you suggested.

Comment: Interesting, my Visual Studio cannot prompt up `CompletedTask` after typing `Task.`.

Comment: @Dai, I still need to call `Run()`. I just don't have anything for the paramter of `f` of `Run()`.

Comment: @Dai `Run` in a user defined method with contains code. Maybe you confused it with `Task.Run`.

Comment: @RufusL `Run` is a user defined method returning a Task. You can definitely use `await` to wait for the method to complete.

Comment: @RufusL We don't know if the method is being called inside a async method or not, I assumed it is, so I added await before it. Fixed the error as well.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I see even in the OP's original post he's calling it with `await`. I'll delete that comment! I like this answer, since it seems more "intentional" than what the OP was originally doing.